# Define bar plot colours according to y value within plotyy

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I want to create a graph that combines a bar plot and a line plot, for which I have the following:

```
[AX,H1,H2] = plotyy(AG_sea_ice(:,6), AG_sea_ice(:,4), TG_FP1(:,5), TG_FP1(:,4), @bar, @line);
set(H1,'FaceColor', [0.6 0.6 0.6], 'EdgeColor', [0.6 0.6 0.6]);
set(H2,'LineStyle',':', 'Color', 'r', 'marker', '+');
```

I also want to color-code the bars in the bar plot according to the y value (instead of having all of the bars coloured grey, as above) for which I have the following, based on previous posts:

```
mydata = AG_sea_ice (:,4);
    bar_h = bar(mydata);
    bar_child=get(bar_h,'Children');
set(bar_child, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
    set(bar_child,'CData', mydata);
set(bar_child,'CDataMapping', 'direct');
    mycolor=[0 0 0; 0.5 0.5 0.5; 1 1 1];

for iCount=1:length(mydata)
    if (mydata(iCount)<5)
    index(iCount)=1;
    elseif(mydata(iCount)>=10)
    index(iCount)=3;
    else
    index(iCount)=2;
    end
    end

set(bar_child, 'CData',index);
colormap(mycolor);
```

My question is how to combine the two, so that the bar colour-coding applies to the bar graph on axis1  within the plotyy graph. Also, if there is a simpler way to approach this problem, please do let me know. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the line
"set(H1,'FaceColor', [0.6 0.6 0.6], 'EdgeColor', [0.6 0.6 0.6]);"
run in MATLAB? I guess the right form is:
set(H1,'Color', [0.6 0.6 0.6]); % 'Color' not 'FaceColor'.